# Create input with height and width dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an input element using javascript. In my code, when I check `element.is(':visible')`, it returns `false` every time. As per [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_visible.asp), maybe this is happening due to height and width of the element is zero at runtime.

So, I tried setting its height and width. But still, I am getting `:visible` and height and width is still coming zero.

[Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/qagf7t6j/4/)

What changes I have to make in my code so that `:visible` becomes `true`. Is there any way to set `:visible` true dynamically?

Comment: What about the other: `Set to display:none, Form elements with type="hidden", Width and height set to 0, A hidden parent element (this also hides child elements)`?

Comment: @sonali see the answer it might help you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is working correctly as you expected.
I included a test code

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("class", "custom-wrapper");
input.style.width = input.style.height = "20px";
input.setAttribute("height", 20);
input.setAttribute("width", 20);
input.value = "";
document.body.appendChild(input);

//test code (is appended element visible)
if ($("input:visible"))
  alert(input.style.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Question is about javascript not for jquery.

Comment: @manikantgautam in a link in the question it's mentioned in link what she/he trying to do

Answer (score 2):

You should have to use `window.getComputedStyle(input)` inorder to get height of element. Here is how. `element.is(':visible')` is not in any picture in your code.

The `window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active `stylesheets` and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual `CSS` property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with `CSS property` names. [more from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("class", "custom-wrapper");
input.style.width = input.style.height = "20px";
input.setAttribute("height", 20);
input.setAttribute("width", 20);
input.value = "";
document.body.appendChild(input);
getHeight();// elemnt is visible
input.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
getHeight(); // element is hidden now
input.style.visibility = "visible"; // Again make it visible
function getHeight(){
if(isVisible(input)){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(input).height);
}else{
 alert('your element is hidden');
}
}

// To check visibility of element.
function isVisible (ele) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
    return  style.width !== "0" &&
    style.height !== "0" &&
    style.opacity !== "0" &&
    style.display!=='none' &&
    style.visibility!== 'hidden';
}
```